# how to flash twrp recovery image file using fastboot in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu-touch, android, flash

I want to flash TWRP recovery using fastboot in my moto E2 LTE. i have installed adb and fastboot using this command

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corbindavenport/nexus-tools/master/install.sh)
```

and also downloaded TWRP image file but don't know in which directory to put that image file in order to flash.

Comment: did you rooted your phone?

Comment: yes i have already rooted.

Comment: I suggest you visit https://forum.xda-developers.com/, they have a great know-how about flashing and recovery mobiles. Everytime I need flash my mobile, I catch knowledge by there.